# Retrieving operation not supported on using send method pyzmq error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, pyzmq

I have the following code sending video frames from the server to the client. I am retrieving error on server.py.

Server.py

```
import base64
import cv2
import zmq
import time
import numpy as np
context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:5555')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))

videoFile = 'SAMPLE.mp4'
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)  # init the camera
length=int(camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
while True:        
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()
    try:
       frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
    except cv2.error:
        break
   
    encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    time.sleep(3)
    footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)
footage_socket.close()
```

Client.py

```
  import cv2,zmq,base64
  import numpy as np
  context = zmq.Context()
  footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
  footage_socket.connect('tcp://10.96.0.1:5555')
  while True:
      frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
      source = cv2.imdecode( np.fromstring( base64.b64decode( frame ), dtype = np.uint8),1 )
```

I am retrieving the below error

```
  footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py", line 391, in send
  return super(Socket, self).send(data, flags=flags, copy=copy, track=track)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 727, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 774, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 249, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._send_copy
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 244, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._send_copy
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
  zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation not supported
```

Help is highly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code attempts to call a `.recv_string()`-method on a `Socket`-class instance, which was created of the type **`PUB`**.

That will never work. `PUB` Scalable Formal Communication Archetype belongs to the some-`PUB`lish + many-can-`SUB`scribe to receive those pieces of all the `PUB`lished data that match their active `SUB`scription details.

There is well documented & published ZeroMQ API specification, which is explicit on this. **`PUB`** can `.send()` but never `.recv()`

The same happens to your `SUB`-socket instance in *`Server.py`*, where your code (as-is) orders a call to `.send()`, which can never happen for a `SUB`-socket.

***`zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation not supported`*** is the only result for such API-colliding attempts.